# Levenberg's original article "A method for the solution of certain problems in least squares"

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-optimization

Does there exist any digital copy of the original article (or a transcript) K. Levenberg, *A method for the solution of certain problems in least-squares*, Quart. Appl. Math. 2 (1944): 164-168?

It is (obviously!) cited in numerous works, but the paper itself appears to have completely vanished. There seems to be not even any publisher, library, etc. proposing to buy a hard copy or anything alike. Apart from the citations all over the places, the paper has ceased to exist?!

(The question has also been posted on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897244/levenbergs-original-article-a-method-for-the-solution-of-certain-problems-in-l))

Comment: You seem to have double posted to MO and M.SE. In such a case it is polite to provide links between the two questions.

Comment: You are right, indeed. Done!

Comment: If you're still having trouble getting this through your library, contact me by email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [link](https://doi.org/10.1090/qam/10666) might be better. The paper is now open access and the pdf is searchable.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. (@PierreSchroeder, it is possible and encouraged to unaccept an answer if a better one comes along). @NiclasBörlin, you might change the link to use the more stable DOI and add that the paper is open access.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, there's no official digitized copy (yet), but I have a hard time agreeing with your statement that no library has a hard copy. For example, looking at the German [Zeitschriftendatenbank](http://dispatch.opac.dnb.de/), you can see that many universities have a copy of that issue, and if you (or someone you know) are at a German university, will probably send you a scanned copy upon request (look for "Fernleihe: Ja").

EDIT: Since there's no full bibliographical detail for the articles in such an old journal, you have to search for the *journal* (i.e., "Quarterly of Applied Mathematics") and not the article. This will get you a search result (it's the second in the list; the first is to the online version), and clicking "Link zum Gateway" at the bottom of the tab "Details" will lead to the "Gateway Bayern", where you will find a link to "SFX", where you can click on "Dokumentlieferung: Fernleihe im Bibliotheksverbund Bayern". Since I no longer have an account at TUM, I cannot follow from there, but I expect you will be presented with a form where you can enter the precise reference (title, volume, issue, pages etc.) you want to have sent.

Of course, this is not nearly as convenient as getting a current online publication, but that's why librarians are still needed. Moral of the story: If you can't find it online (in reasonable time), take the full reference and ask your librarian. They're trained to help you with precisely such a problem!

Comment: I have to admit that your answer is correct (although it does not solve my problem in practice)! I unfortunately have to conclude that an OPAC request is not necessarily an OPAC (the TUM-UB didn't show any other library's results, and their first release of that journal is 1945!).

I suppose as far as I can get.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder I just received the scan of our library's copy of the paper; if the steps above don't work for you, feel free to contact me by email.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but is [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/43633451?seq=1#fndtn-page_scan_tab_contents) what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=A+METHOD+FOR+THE+SOLUTION+OF+CERTAIN+NON-LINEAR+PROBLEMS+IN+LEAST+SQUARES&acc=on&wc=on&fc=off&group=none

http://www.jstor.org/

Username: skylinehs
Password: spartans